# WPF: Which collection class to use

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, observablecollection, bindinglist

After spending a whole day trying different suggestions, I'm back at square 1. I'm trying to bind my view, a XAML Window, to one of my ViewModel properties, say, SalesOrders. The ViewModel in turn talks to the Model (an EF Model on top of a database). The question I'm facing is the collection type that I should use to expose my SalesOrders property.

I have tried the following types, none of which does all of what I need.

1. `List<T>`
2. `ObservableCollection<T>`
3. `BindingList<T>`
4. `CollectionViewSource` on top of the above

Here's what I need my collection to do:

1. The view has Previous/Next buttons, so the collection should provide some sort of currency manager.
2. There's a Save button in the view, which I need to get enabled/disabled **immediately** based on whether the SalesOrder collection has any changes. Since `SalesOrder` is already an EF type, all of its fields implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

`CollectionViewSource` provides me with navigation methods (previous/next) but doesn't listen to PropertyChanged events, so modifying data in the view doesn't turn the Save button on. `BindingList` can listen to PropertyChanged events, but doesn't provide navigation methods. `ObservableCollection` lacks both functionalities.

TIA.

Comment: Sounds like you should roll your own.

Comment: Couldn't you just hook up to `PropertyChanged` event of the Model when you add to your `CollectionViewSource` and unhook when you remove? Then, in your handler for PropertyChanged, re-query your save button's command (which I'm assuming is bound to an `ICommand`)

Comment: Why does your collection `need` to do that? Isn't that what the ViewModel is for? You can always roll your own class exposing a collection like @Will suggested.

Comment: Ryan: A View shouldn't be talking to the Model, or should it?
Bob: Having a truly "observable collection" is so often required. After all, that's why we have all these bindable collections in the framework. Doing this manually in the VM for each and every collection-type property would be like reinventing the same wheel again and again.

As Will said, I ended up creating my own ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `ObservableCollection<T>` then subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event to enable or disable your save button as outlined in the answer of the thread [MVVM ObservableCollection Bind TwoWay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224917/mvvm-observablecollection-bind-twoway).

Comment: Read my question. ObservableCollection does not raise CollectionChanged when one of the items in it changes (modifies one of its properties).

Comment: @dotNET please read the second part that says "If you need to track changes to the objects within the collection you have to build a extended ObservableCollection...."

Comment: Ah I see. That is what I ended up with. So in a sense, this does answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN about CollectionView [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx):

> In WPF applications, all collections have an associated default
>   collection view. Rather than working with the collection directly, the
>   binding engine always accesses the collection through the associated
>   view. To get the default view, use the
>   CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView method. An internal class based on
>   CollectionView is the default view for collections that implement only
>   IEnumerable. ListCollectionView is the default view for collections
>   that implement IList. BindingListCollectionView is the default view
>   for collections that implement IBindingListView or IBindingList.

Which means you can use BindingList for SalesOrders and bind it in the View, then to manage the navigation you can access its automatically created CollectionView from the ViewModel with:

```
myCollectionView = (BindingListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.SalesOrders);
```